# get url of dynamic html template in spring boot rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want to send dynamic rendered html template and send its url as a message to the phone,( I have an api for that )
I am using Model and View and setting the dynamic data but how do I get its dynamic urls what are the approaches to achieve that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to get the current URL in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Thymeleaf to render your Html and save it temporary with a unique name.

[How to do it exactly is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962612/get-raw-html-from-the-controller-spring-thymeleaf)

Now you need a @Controller with a @Getmapping.

```
 @GetMapping("/htmls/{unique}")
 @ResponseBody 
 public String ResponsePerson(
 @PathVariable("unique") String unique) {
    
   return htmlString
}
```

You can get the Html String in diff. Ways.
One example way is:

```
File htmlFile = new File("src/main/ress/htmls/"+unique+"html");
String htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlFile, 
                                               StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Your link should look like: `http//:yor.ip.adress:8080/htmls/unique`

Edit: Sorry forgot to add the @ResponseBody Annotation.
You need that to bind the returned String to the Web Response Body.